# abstract service interfaces Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

Let's say I have two service interfaces (using retrofit).

```
interface ReminderService {
    @GET("reminder" + "/list")
    Observable<Response<Reminder>> getList(@HeaderMap Map<String, String> headerMap);

    @POST("reminder" + "/ins")
    Observable<Response<Reminder>> ins(@HeaderMap Map<String, String> headerMap);
}

interface FileService {
    @GET("file" + "/list")
    Observable<Response<Reminder>> getList(@HeaderMap Map<String, String> headerMap);

    @POST("file" + "/ins")
    Observable<Response<Reminder>> ins(@HeaderMap Map<String, String> headerMap);
}
```

the only difference between this two interfaces is the tableName **reminder** and **file**

and since the annotation **GET** and **POST** don't accept methods inside.

is there a way to abstract them?

Comment: I don't belive you can just abstract them but you could pass table name as `@Path` argument.

Answer (score 1):

Kindly check this code.

```
@GET("{tableName}/list")
fun getList(@Path("tableName") path : String,
            @HeaderMap headerMap: Map<String, String>
): Observable<Response<Reminder>>

@POST("{tableName}/ins")
fun ins(@Path("tableName") path : String,
        @HeaderMap headerMap: Map<String, String>
): Observable<Response<Reminder>>
```

Now here is the code from where you have to call this method.

```
getList("reminder", headerMap)
getList("file", headerMap)
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: Even better: `@GET("{tableName}/list")`